# Why QSpinBox jumps twice the Step value

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt5

I have a simple python qt application in which I want to plot something dynamically via matplotlib. I was trying to follow instructions like [this](http://blog.rcnelson.com/building-a-matplotlib-gui-with-qt-designer-part-3/) and [that](https://www.boxcontrol.net/embedding-matplotlib-plot-on-pyqt5-gui.html). It works as expected except for one thing, my spinbox updates twice upon mouse click and I do not understand why. Well, during the development the `valueChanged.connect()` worked fine until I got to a certain point. Then the `update_figure()` was called twice and the displayed value jumped by two instead of the desired one. I tried to make a minimum working example, you find below. Without the `sleep` command in `update_figue` my spinbox behaves normal, with `sleep` it is called twice and the value jumps by two, with an delay given by `sleep`.

Why does the `sleep` in `update_figure` influence the spinbox, or what is happening here? Is it the way I constructed the `connect()`?

BTW: I observed the same behaviour on a slider.

Cheers

(I do not think it matters, but this is on openSuse Leap)

**EDIT:** I could make the example even "more minimal".

```
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys
from time import sleep

Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow = loadUiType('main.ui')

class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.spinBox_dac.valueChanged.connect(self.update_figure)

    def update_figure(self):
        ##### The following line makes the difference!
        sleep(1) #####################################
        ##### why?
        print "damn...once or twice?"       
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()    
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the main.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>185</width>
    <height>107</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Maximum">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>1100</width>
    <height>905</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>mini</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QSpinBox" name="spinBox_dac">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>61</width>
      <height>28</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="minimum">
     <number>3</number>
    </property>
    <property name="maximum">
     <number>20</number>
    </property>
    <property name="singleStep">
     <number>1</number>
    </property>
    <property name="value">
     <number>4</number>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sleep()` call prevent qt to process the mouse-release and the `QSpinBox` "thinks" that the mouse is pressed long enough to increase/decrease the value again (auto-repeat).

See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-33128

A solution could be:

```
def update_figure(self):
    for _ in xrange(10):
        QApplication.processEvents() 
        sleep(0.1)
    print "Only once :-)"
```

Anyway it's not a good practice to block the UI while performing long operations, the work is usually delegated to another thread.

#### EDIT

This affect `Qt4` and `Qt5` both, but it behave a bit differently.

There is no `setAutoRepeat` because in the `QAbstrectSpinBox` this behavior is implemented using styles, while in `QAbstractButton` is implemented with a timer.

The way around this is to create a `ProxyStyle` and set a very long "auto-repeat" interval

```
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QProxyStyle, QStyle
import sys
from time import sleep

Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow = loadUiType('main.ui')


class CustomStyle(QProxyStyle):
    def styleHint(self, hint, option=None, widget=None, returnData=None):
        if hint == QStyle.SH_SpinBox_KeyPressAutoRepeatRate:
            return 10**10
        elif hint == QStyle.SH_SpinBox_ClickAutoRepeatRate:
            return 10**10
        elif hint == QStyle.SH_SpinBox_ClickAutoRepeatThreshold:
            # You can use only this condition to avoid the auto-repeat,
            # but better safe than sorry ;-)
            return 10**10
        else:
            return super().styleHint(hint, option, widget, returnData)


class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.spinBox_dac.setStyle(CustomStyle())
        self.spinBox_dac.valueChanged.connect(self.update_figure)

    def update_figure(self):
        sleep(1)
        print "Only once!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()    
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for this interesting info. So this is a bug or a feature? More important, why does the QSpinBox not have a setAutoRepeat() method, in contrast to, e.g., a PushButton, as it obviously has an autorepeat? Or in other words, how do I switch it off? Unfortunately, the time consuming process cannot be split in a for loop as in your answer. Whether or not it is a good idea to push this calculation into a different thread, is a different question.

Comment: This is a qt5 problem only?

Comment: Is not considered a bug, if you see the bug report it's marked as `invalid`, see the updated answer.

Comment: Nice, it seems that QRoxyStyle is not available in 5.4, though; so I need to update to 5.7 first. Then I will fiddle with this workaround.

Comment: `QProxyStyle` should be available from qt 4.6, as you can see from the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html)

Comment: @Ceppo93. PyQt is not Qt. The `QProxyStyle` class was only added in PyQt-5.5 (and will probably never be supported in PyQt4).

Comment: I know the difference, but not that this class was not included in the binding ... :)

Comment: Ok, so lets see when I get this updated. Until then my workaround is actually using the `editingFinished` signal. Unfortunately the `mouseRelease()` does not send this, such that I have to derive a class from `QspinBox` and emit this manually on `mouseRelease`.